# Wordpress 5 strange behavior when logged in, to elements with 100% height

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I already searched for answers on google but didn't found any. Maybe anyone of you can help me here.

On several websites of me (Wordpress 5.0.4 or greater), I have the following strange behavior:

When I am logged in, elements with a height of 100% are rendered completely different as when I am not logged in.

[image: Not logged in]

[image: logged in]

All are custom templates.

I could change the the css of all sites, but I don't want to make (maybe) unnecessary code work. So if anyone can tell me a suitable solution, I would appreciate it.

Comment: can you share your website link?

Comment: http://www.hutter.at

Comment: hmm, I didn't notice that the issue is for logged in users, and I can't log in to the website. but you definitely need some CSS tweaks to get it resolved. Try adding this code to your CSS file `.frontpage-wrapper .tile { height: auto !important; }`

Comment: hmm... the strange thin is, that it worked normal before the wordpress updates... so there is maybe a problem with the admin css of wordpress generally ?

Comment: Admin CSS of WordPress will not effect on the front-end, I think the issue is due to incompatibility of your theme or plugins with the WP 5. Try updating your theme and plugins to their latest version. Don't forget to backup your site 

Comment: as i mentioned before, it is a custom theme... never the less, the behavior is only when you are logged in, in the backend ;)  so there must be a connection between wordpress and the frontend.